# Cambiar color elemento menu

Tags: html, css

Hola tengo el siguiente menu y me gustaria hacer con CSS que al pulsar a uno de los li ese li se mantenga de un color. De esta forma el usuario sabria mientras navega por ese li que esta en ese li.

```
<nav>
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Index.html">Index</a></li>
                <li><a href="pedidos.html">Haz un pedido</a></li>
                <li><a href="contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

He probado esto pero no se mantiene el color

> li a:active{
>       background-color: green ;
>     }

Comment: Con css no puedes hacer eso dinámicamente, tendrías que ponerle una clase especifica al `li` correspondiente para cada página

Answer (score 5):

Necesitaría algo más de información para darte una respuesta más concreta a tu caso, pero aquí te dejo un par de soluciones:

**HTML y CSS:**
Si escribes el menú que has mostrado en cada una de las páginas que se ven (Index.html, pedidos.html y contacto.html), podrías aplicar una clase al li que corresponda en esa página, por ejemplo, el menú en pedidos.html sería así:

```css
li.active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Index.html">Index</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="pedidos.html">Haz un pedido</a></li>
            <li><a href="contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**HTML, CSS y JS:** En este caso, al pulsar una de las opciones del menú deberías llevar a cabo dos acciones con JS que podrías poner en una función y llamarla en el onclick.
 1. Eliminar la clase "active" del menú en el que esté activo. Para ello puedes seleccionar todas las opciones del listado, recorrerlas e ir eliminado la clase.
 2. Añadir la clase "active" a la opción seleccionada del menú. Para ello solo debes acceder a la propiedad className del elemento li seleccionado.

Answer (score 2):

Una opción que te puede servir es ir cambiado clases css, dándole y quitándole propiedades para que se comporte como tu quieres. Te dejo a continuación un ejemplo, espero que te sea útil:

```
li.active{
  background-color: red;
  padding: 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all .5s;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

 li:focus, li:hover, li:active{
  background-color: red;
  padding: 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all .5s;
  margin-left: 15px;
}


 <nav>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Index</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Haz un pedido</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Como bien te han respondido, lo que pides tiene varias maneras de hacerlo por eso no estaría de más que en la propia pregunta especifiques que solución es la que buscas.
En cuanto a la solución yo e usado un un nav de boostrap y tan solo le he añadido el JQuery necesario para conseguir el efecto que quieres:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title></title>
    <style media="screen">
      *{
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
      }
      nav{
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: #959595;
      }
      ul{
        list-style: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#" id="inicio">AAAA</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">BBBB</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">CCCC</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">DDDD</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('li').click(function(){
          $('li').each(function(){
           //Recorremos todos los "li" para quitarles los fondos
            $(this).css('background-color', '');
          });
          //Se lo añadimos al que se le hace el click
          $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Lo que hace básicamente es mirar todos los tag li que se encuentra en el HTML y primero les pone la propiedad "backgroud-color" en blanco para quitarle el fondo al tag li que ya lo tubiese,**este caso se daría cuando el usuario haga su segundo click en otro tag li, es decir, cuando quira cambiar de vista**. Por último le añade al li seleccionado el fondo con el color especificado, en este caso el **ROJO**.

**IMPORTANTE PARA ESTE SCRIPT ES NECESARIO QUE INCLUYAS LA *API DE JQUERY* O BIEN POR LINK(COMO YO) O BIEN TE LO DESCARGAS Y LE PONES LA RUTA EN EL SRC**

Espero que sea esto lo que estas buscando.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitaría algo más de información para darte una respuesta más concreta a tu caso, pero aquí te dejo un par de soluciones:

`HTML` y `CSS`: Si escribes el menú que has mostrado en cada una de las páginas que se ven **Index.html, pedidos.html y contacto.html**, podrías aplicar una clase al `li` que corresponda en esa página, por ejemplo, el menú en **pedidos.html** sería así:

`HTML`, `CSS` y `JS`: En este caso, al pulsar una de las opciones del menú deberías llevar a cabo dos acciones con `JS` que podrías poner en una función y llamarla en el `onclick`.

1. Eliminar la clase `active` del menú en el que esté activo. Para ello puedes seleccionar todas las opciones del listado, recorrerlas e ir eliminado la clase.
2. Añadir la clase `active` a la opción seleccionada del menú. Para ello solo debes acceder a la propiedad `className` del elemento `li` seleccionado.